# Control sum in network connection

Tags: math, networking, controls, sum

i'm making network application which doesn't send good data every time (most of time they are broken) so i tought to make control sum. At the end of data i will add control sum to check if they are valid. So i'm not sure is that a good idea to multiply every data (they are from 1 to 100) by 100, 100^2, 100^3..., and sum them. 
Do you have any suggestion what to do, without making really big number(there are many data in the every packet).
Example:
Data: 1,4,2,77,12,32,5,52,23
My solution:1,4,2,77,12,32,5,52,23, 100+40000+2000000+ 77*10^4 ...
When client receive the packet he will check if last data is equal to sum of other datas.
Is there any better solution?

Comment: Do you mean 'checksum'? It sounds like what you need is a CRC (Cyclic Redundancy Check). Or else to fix your network code :-)

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying the data results in a very large number to transmit, and not a lot of confidence that the numbers are correct.  And addition runs into potential overflow issues.  That is why it is customary to use an xor.

Or you can read up on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error-correcting_code to get even fancier solutions that can detect, and sometimes correct, small numbers of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Best explanation here:

http://www.textfiles.com/programming/crc.txt

CRC functions will be available in you language's networking library.

Answer (score 0):

Because 128 is 10000000 in binary, there is only 1 bit for subnetting, and there are 7 bits for hosts. We're going to subneting the Class C network  address 192.168.10.0.

```
     192.168.10.0 = Network address
     255.255.255.128= Subnet mask
```